# How to determine a python process with pdb whether running or waiting for stdin?

Tags: python, pdb

I am trying to obtain the running state (such as variable dumps) of a Python program named `A`. Currently, I have created a debug script that spawns a Pdb subprocess to debug `A` and control it by sending debugger commands. This allows me to access any variable from the debugger.

However, the A program requires input from `stdin` at certain points. It seems that the Pdb and `A` are somehow sharing the `stdin` stream. When the Pdb is waiting for a command, it displays a `(Pdb)` prompt, indicating that I should input a command. Yet, when `A` is waiting for `stdin`, it does not print anything, giving the impression that it is still running.

Hence, I would like to know how to determine whether the subprocess is actively running or waiting for `stdin` input.

Here's my debugger code, works but not perfect.

```
import os, fire, re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def wait(proc, timeout):
    try:
        proc.wait(timeout)
    except:
        pass

def send(proc, str = None):
    proc.stdin.write((str + '\n').encode())
    proc.stdin.flush()

def recv(proc):
    all = ''
    while True:
        out = proc.stdout.readline()
        if out == b'':
            wait(proc, 0.2)
            out = proc.stdout.readline()
            if out == b'':
                break
        all += out.decode()
    return all

def parse_array(str):
    str = str.strip('[]')
    return [s.strip() for s in str.split(',')]

def get_code_status(proc):
    send(proc, 'locals().keys()')
    m = re.match(r'.*dict_keys\((\[.*\])\).*', recv(proc))
    assert len(m.groups()) == 1
    names = []
    for var in parse_array(m.group(1)):
        stripped = var.strip("'")
        if not re.match(r'__.*__', stripped):
            names.append(f'{var}:{stripped}')
    if names:
        send(proc, '{' + f'{",".join(names)}' + '}')
        status = recv(proc).splitlines()[0]
        send(proc, 'll')
        code = recv(proc)
        return code, status
    return None, None

def main(code, data, output):
    code = os.path.abspath(code)
    proc = Popen(
        ["python", "-m", "pdb", code],
        stdin=PIPE,
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=PIPE
        )
    wait(proc, 1)
    os.set_blocking(proc.stdout.fileno(), False)

    data = open(data).read().splitlines()

    prev_line = 0
    for step in range(100000):
        received = recv(proc)

        if (step + 1) % 10 == 0:
            code, status = get_code_status(proc)
            if code:
                print(code)
                print(status)
            break

        if received == '':
            if data == []:
                break
            else:
                send_line = data.pop(0)
                print(send_line)
                send(proc, send_line)
        else:
            print(received, end='')
            assert received.endswith('(Pdb) ')
            for recv_line in received.splitlines():
                if recv_line.startswith('> '):
                    if code not in recv_line:
                        cmd = 'r'
                    else:
                        m = re.match(r'> (.*)\((\d+)\).*', recv_line)
                        assert len(m.groups()) == 2
                        assert m.group(1) == code
                        cur_line = int(m.group(2))
                        cmd = 'r' if prev_line == cur_line else 's'
                        prev_line = cur_line
                    break
            send(proc, cmd)
            print(cmd)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(main)
```